# Remove extra padding in DataGridView column label?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I am trying to reduce the width of so it displays how I wish in my form. I am having issues "removing" the extra padding in the column names when reducing the size of the `DataGridView`.

[image]

On the left is the table as I originally had it, I realized that I would like it smaller so I decreased its width. The center image represents the smallest the columns will go before the text wraps to the next line. The right image is the size I would like the table to be, I have shown that the text "(px)" will fit in the space.

I have gone through all of the settings I can find in the designer and have not found anything to help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my example. Although it might not be the best solution but worked.


I measured the exact width of `HeaderCell`'s content ("Height (px)") and set the column's width with some additional padding (For example, 9).

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False;
Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText, dataGridView1.Font);
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = textSize.Width + 9; // Adding some padding
```

Comment: mmm, I need but for 30 columns ... some way to set multiple properties for one column at the same time? and is there any way to apply this in a loop for 30 columns with a counter?