# C# minimise width of DataGridLayout columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to set the width of DataGridView columns to the width of the header text label?

Comment: This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377372/remove-extra-padding-in-datagridview-column-label) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `ColumnHeader` should be what you are looking for. [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)